# How a mobile app will refresh access_token without refresh_token ? Implicit grant/ OAuth 2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, openid-connect

As said in  [OAuth2 rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-10)

> The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens **(it does not
> support the issuance of refresh tokens)** and is optimized for public
> clients known to operate a particular redirection URI.  These clients
> are typically implemented in a browser using a scripting language

Refresh tokens are not suitable for implicit grant.
My question is:

- How a mobile app, will refresh the *access_token* once it expires?
- How the big ones in the market are doing this? Which practices they follow?
- I know it is not following security recomendations, but it´s a good practice to make an long-lived *access_token* in this case? It can get annoying to need to re-authenticate each 30 min you use an app, or you close and reopen it.
- As necessary permissions don´t change, a silent log-in on every app start, will be a choice to consider?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a refresh token to allow continued usage once an access token expires. If you must insist your clients use the implicit flow, then they may be able to make use of cookies and redirects to keep getting short-lived tokens without user interaction. Providing your client apps are using an HTTP agent which can use permanent cookies. e.g. apps that run in a web browser.

The key then is keeping the user signed into the identity provider the first time the token is requested.

This is done for example by the Identity provider (you I guess?) creating an HTTP cookie for the user agent to persist. Most big identity providers will do this - i.e. keep you signed in.

Now, when the token expires your client app will send the user back through the Oauth process again but, because the user has remained logged in to the identity provider, the identity provider can authenticate the user from the cookie without prompting for credentials.

If your clients instigate this token renewal on a background thread they can request the token as normal and, through the magic of HTTP redirects and cookies, get back a new token from you with no user action required.

Again - this alternative to refresh tokens relies on the client device being able to utilise permanent cookies, and your users remaining signed in and your auth server handling http cookies. If your clients are using native apps this solution may not work.

As in the future you will have 100s of clients maybe your auth plaform should offer different auth flows to different clients.

This article on [mobile apps and implicit flow](https://medium.com/@justinsecurity/mobile-apps-and-oauths-implicit-flow-68e72c6515a1) may be of interest to you.

Comment: it´s safe to store a cookie that acts like a non revocable refresh_token ?If someone steals it , steals the user identity. It will make more sense to issue a refresh token, because it will be the same in security terms but you can revoke them

Comment: You're app doesn't store it and can't access it. Your user's http agent stores them and they are safe as they are bound to the users device and only used by the identity provider. When requesting a token for a signed-in user, the identify provider can still check the user has consented your app and that the user is still valid - it just won't require the user to reenter credentials.

Comment: @iandayman So lets say user kept signed in within the browser. how do you get a token in the background from the browser? Don't you have to open the browser with the authorization url? Can that be done in background?

Answer (score 0):

Native apps are supposed to use the Auth code grant. So you can use refresh tokens. There is an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) that discusses reasons (mainly security) for that as well as platform specific details. There is an important implication - the `/token` endpoint of your OAuth2 provider should not require authentication for getting tokens, because your application cannot keep its client secret safe.

Comment: The mobile.app is from a third party, and they want to use our system to authenticate and authorize  so I think native app is not the best fit, We don’t think mobile app can save safely the secret code

Comment: A mobile app is native for its platform. What do you mean by the "secret code"? So your question is not about the app, but how to use the Implicit grant even if it's not safe?

Comment: It s a third party app which will integrated in our auth platform.

Comment: In the future they will be hundreds,and we don’t care about how they are coded, we jut suposse they can not ensure client-secret confidenciality

Comment: what happen if a hacker descompress the APK Android app and get both client_id and client_secret. I think you answer is not correct

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you cannot keep the client secret in your application, so the token endpoint should be configured to not require it. Please read the linked RFC, it's not long and it contains valuable information.

Comment: So, how i will refresh access_token silently?

Comment: Using a refresh token if using the code grant. And if you really want to use the Implicit grant, it's possible use the `prompt=none` request param from [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest).

Comment: Ok, as I said we need implicit grant 100%. If we use prompt=none what happens if the user credentials are not saved in the  external user-agent?

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you have to use the Implicit grant before. If you want to use it, it's up to you how you implement it, the OAuth2 protocol is not designed to work securely in that combination (Implicit grant + native app).

Comment: Is written in the title of the question. So how mobile apps should work with Oauth2 ?

Comment: See the linked [RFC 8252](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8252), which also links the PKCE extension, [RFC 7636](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636). That's how native apps should do OAuth2.